# create a search filter with data grid in XPages

Tags: datagrid, xpages, lotus

I'm working with an XPages named "HISTORY" gathering and grouping all the documents in a database (.nsf)
I want to create a filter that shows me only documents created between two dates "start date" and "End Date"
I worked with data grid but loading of view was very long and heavy
I do not know how to do. Any suggestion?

and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use **full text search** to get a fast access to documents created between two dates.

Set **search** property of selected REST service to e.g.:

```
"[_CreationDate] >= 01/01/2015 and [_CreationDate] < 01/01/2016"
```

`[_CreationDate]` is the place holder for document's creation date in full text search queries.

The same applies for dominoView data sources in case you want to use view panel or data table instead of data grid.

Comment: datagrid dont load any thing when i Set the query : 
"[_CreationDate] >= 01/01/2015 and [_CreationDate] < 01/01/2016" 
in search property of selected REST.
and if i set the query in the event of the search button , datgrid load all document ==> so heavy 
and if i click the search button nothing was loading also.

Comment: Which REST service do you use? Do you have documents created in 2015? Is full text search activated in your database? What happens if you change full text search to something you know it works like [Form]="yourFormName"?